# Is shopping near dargah is permissible for believers

Tags: punishment, shirk, uloom-al-hadith

Is shopping near dargah is permissible for believers,here in India people celebrate urus(visiting graves and celebrating vali Allah's birthday) and their will lots of stuff for shopping, eating, can a believer just go for shopping without visiting their grave

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site. We expect you to have done some prior research before asking a question, show it. I mean what actually makes you think it shouldn't be permissible?

Comment: @Medi1Saif In the subcontinent, most of the tomb caretakers have established shops around the shrines and take advantage of people's ignorance. Some of them sell stuff telling this is blessed by the person in the grave or his descendants and will be beneficial. Others simply sell normal food and water.  Whereas there are some who sell flowers and sheets to be placed on the tombs a percentage of which again goes to the caretakers of the dargah. I assume is specific to the time of Urs when the birth of the now deceased religious person is celebrated commonly through Sufi music, dances and food.

Comment: AFAIK most of what happens in such an area is foreign to Islam and has been taken from local Hindu practices. Not surprisingly a significant number of attendees are Hindus. This topic is a matter of religious debate in the sub continent and has proponents on both sides. If only the Ulema were strong enough today to expose the Bidah.